# Is there a sum(min_count=1) that is as fast as sum on DataFrameGroupBy.agg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a few million rows that I groupby and sum various columns via

```
df.groupby(…).agg({
  "foo": "sum",
  "bar": "sum",
  …})
```

That is rather fast and takes around 10 seconds on my machine.

Now I need a variant of sum that keeps NaN values, like

```
sum(min_count=1)
```

The only way this seems to work with the groupby/agg from above is via

```
... agg({
  "foo": (lambda s: s.sum(min_count=1))
})
```

But that is upto 10x slower.

I tried passing kwargs but these seem not to be propagated when passing a dict to agg:

```
... agg({
  "foo": "sum",
  "bar": "sum",
}, min_count=1)
```

Is there a way to group/agg with the semantics of min_count=1 and the speed of a bare sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the gist of the issue is the fact, that you can replace:
`df.groupby(...).agg({"col1": func0, "col2": func0})` with `df.groupby(...)[["col1", "col2"]].func0()`.

In your case:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"x": list("aabbbaa"), "y": [1,1,None,None,None,None,None], "z": [None,None,3,None,None,None,None]})
>>> df.groupby("x")[["y", "z"]].sum(min_count=1)
     y    z
x
a  2.0  NaN
b  NaN  3.0
```

which then in turn permits you to leverage full capability of `pd.DataFrame.sum()` per [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum)

Comment: Great – and for different ways of aggregating different columns I can just recombine the columns afterwards.  So many ways to achieve something in Pandas 

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `sum` as aggfunc for all columns, you can do:

```
df.groupby(...).sum(min_count=1)
```

---

Using this dataframe for example:

```
   a    b    c
0  1  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN
2  2  1.0  3.0
3  2  2.0  4.0
```

This:

```
df.groupby("a").sum(min_count=1)
```

Would return:

```
     b    c
a          
1  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  7.0
```

---

If you want to aggregate specific columns, you can select them after grouping:

```
   a    b    c    d
0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  2  1.0  3.0  0.0
3  2  2.0  4.0  0.0
```

Selecting `'b'` and `'c'` for example:

```
df = df.groupby("a")[["b", "c"]].sum(min_count=1)
```

Would return:

```
     b    c
a          
1  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could try is using numpy directly within a custom aggregation function

```
import numpy as np

def sum_with_min_count(s):
    return np.nansum(s.to_numpy())

result = df.groupby(...).agg({
    "foo": sum_with_min_count,
    "bar": sum_with_min_count,
    # Add other columns as needed
})
```